# Windows cannot connect to Enterprise WPA2 WiFi access point with EAP-TTLS PAP authentication using freeradius

Tags: linux, window, wifi-configuration, ldap, freeradius

I was working on having an **Enterprise WiFi access point** where my clients need to enter username and password (which are in OpenLDAP directory), using **AES, TTLS PAP.**

I setup my freeradius according to this tutorial: https://ttboa.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/freeradius-on-debian-7/

and everything **worked perfectly when my clients use Android phone**.

**BUT the problem** is: I tried for a couple of days trying to get **WINDOWS** to be able to connect to my Access point with no success.
We the clients try to connect from windows 10, they get a propt window to enter username and password WITH DOMAIN.
I tried with the client using my server domain, and without entering domain, with no success. It just doesn't connect.

Here is freeradius log: http://pastebin.com/EKGzXDdm

the username in OpenLDAP is: "alice@mneserver.mooo.com", it was just alice but I edited it just to try with domain.
the password of that user is "m". and the password is **md5** hashed in LDAP.

I am really confused and don't know what to do to solve that, I google everywhere with no success, any help is really very appreciated.

Comment: [How does this question differ from your existing question?](http://superuser.com/questions/1030167/cannot-connect-with-wpa2-aes-encryption-eap-ttls-pap-with-freeradius-auth)

Comment: @Ramhound I posted the solution for the other one :) this is another problem, the former the problem was in AES
you meant this one, you can find the solution down
http://superuser.com/questions/1030167/cannot-connect-with-wpa2-aes-encryption-eap-ttls-pap-with-freeradius-auth?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally after a couple of days of debugging and searching I got it!

If we check the log deltaily, we will find that there is something wrong with the ciphers, that word remembered me that a couple of days ago I edited the **ciphers_list in eap.conf** trying to solve another problem and I didn't set them back, and now when I set them back to **default**, everything worked in both windows and android like a charm :)